# Application creation

Tags: android, web-applications

Hey guys I'm just a student styding computer programming and i would like to learn how to make an app, I just learn c and java but i'm newbie and i wonder if java applications work on android etc, I did some research but I'm still confused also I couldn't find a proper tutorial just to learn the basics.
I would appreciate if someone could help me a bit just to understand how things work but if you think that this is a dumb question,forgive me but I need some guide.
Sorry if I wasted your time and for my spelling!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can learn from here http://developer.android.com/index.html but i don't understand the  question "java applications work on android" i am not sure what you mean